# How to code this C++ function in C#?

Tags: c#, c++

I have the following function in C++:

```
void put8At ( unsigned char *b, int pos, int v )
{
    union
    {
        short a;
        unsigned char b[2];
    } u;

    u.a = v;
    b += pos;
    *b = v & 0xff;
}
```

How would you code this in C#?

Comment: I think you should try to do it by yourself before..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how I would code it in C++:

```
void put8At ( unsigned char *b, int pos, int v )
{
    b[pos] = v & 0xff;
}
```

This is probably easier to translate to C# now.

Comment: How do you justify the changes?

Comment: I'm very new to this thing, and this is not my code... Could you explain me why isn't it good?

Comment: You're new to this, and you choose such a clusterf*/$ as an example? Do you even know what your code does? FYI, the sample Martinho posted does something different from what you originally had. The & 0xff always happens on the last 8 bits in his code, for yours it lets the bits on pos pass.

Comment: @Anton I have no idea what you are trying to say, but you are wrong http://ideone.com/kR3FQP. The code I posted has the same observable behaviour as the code in the question. Perhaps you could be so kind as to post an example where the behaviour of the two differs?

Comment: @typedeftypename: The `u.a = v;` line writes to a local variable that is never again used. So I dropped it, and the whole union declaration too. `b[pos]` is equal to `*(b+pos)`, so I replace `b+=pos; *b ...` with simply `b[pos]` (there is no need to assign to b because it is local and never used after this).

Comment: Ah, right, I missread the code.